# Error to implemente async-await function

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous

at this moment I am improving the code of this question, using async-await.

I wish to obtain the "films" of https://swapi.co/api/people/1/

I implement a for to go through all the elements of the json, but I get different errors, I put it in different positions to iterate in different ways, but none works.

I would like to know if you can evaluate the code and support me.

Use babel to transpile the code and use it https://babeljs.io/repl

```js
function handleError(err) {
 console.log(`Request failed: ${err}`); 
}

async function getLuke() {
  try{
      const response = await fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/');
      const luke = await response.json();
      const responseHomeWorld = await fetch(luke.homeworld);
      const responseSpecies = await fetch(luke.species);
      for(let f = 0;f<luke.films.length; f++) {
       const responseFilms = await fetch(luke.films[f]);
       luke.films = await responseFilms.json();
        console.log(`${films.title}`);
      }
      
      luke.homeworld = await responseHomeWorld.json();
      luke.species = await responseSpecies.json();
      
      console.log(`${luke.name} it's a ${luke.species.name} That was born in ${luke.homeworld.name}`);
      
      
    } catch (err) {
      handleError(err); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are getting isn't json, the correct URL is https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json

Comment: Replacing `luke.films =` inside a loop over `luke.films` is a bad idea. Did you mean to assign to `luke.films[f]`?

Comment: "*but I get different errors*" - which errors? If you don't tell us what problems you have, we cannot help you with them.

Comment: ERROR:   Request failed: ReferenceError: films is not defined

Comment: I want to show the title of each of the values ​​of films, the route would be luke.films.title for each "Film"